# No provider for PageScrollService ng2-page-scroll

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ng2-page-scroll in my application. I am getting error like "No provider for PageScrollService!". Please find the below code,

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PageScrollService, Ng2PageScrollModule } from 'ng2-page-scroll'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div id='start' style='height: 1000px;'>
  <h1>Hello Angular</h1> <br>
  </div>
  <h1> Completed </h1>
  <a pageScroll [pageScrollDuration]="2000" href="#start"> click </a>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; 

 

}
```

I have import this PageScrollService in app module also. Please try to give solution on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need import and call the forRoot method of Ng2PageScrollModule in you root module (ie: AppModule) in order to provide the service and use it from anywhere.

```
import {Ng2PageScrollModule} from 'ng2-page-scroll/ng2-page-scroll';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* Other imports here */
    Ng2PageScrollModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```